# How can empty href and src affect app server?

Tags: html, spring, internet-explorer, jboss, yslow

My web app is running on JBoss App Sever and based on SpringMVC. The app is tested in Internet Explorer 9.

I've faced a bug, when the server's memory was 99% used. After analyzing logs, I've noticed that bug occurred when the user was executing operation that sends POSTs request to the server, in addition, some GETs were sent before and those GETs are should not be sent (This GET is executed only to redirect to the page when I'm entering to it for the first time). In other words, in scenario without bugs, the sequence of GETs and POSTs should be `GET, POST, POST, POST, POST, ...`, but when the server is out of memory and front-end works with bugs, the sequence is `GET, POST, GET, POST, POST, GET, POST, ...`. Initially I was unable to understand why GETs were executed, but then I've found [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/46115-controller-called-twice-in-one-request-when-changed-the-view) discussion and concluded that it is caused by `href="#"` on the page. Then I've read [more](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/) about it. Where I've marked this paragraph:

> The second problem is user state corruption. If you’re tracking state in the request, either by cookies or in another way, you have the possibility of destroying data. Even though the image request doesn’t return an image, all of the headers are read and accepted by the browser, including all cookies. While the rest of the response is thrown away, the damage may already be done.

1) As I understand, the GET's that I had were `Internet Explorer makes a request to the directory in which the page is located`, am I right?

2) Why it was happening only when the server's memory was 99% used?

So I've removed all empty hrefs that page had end redeployed application. The bug have disappeared. Then I've added empty hrefs again and redeployed the app, but was unable to reproduce the same bug as I had before.

3) Can you recommend me how can I reproduce the `user state corruption` again in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is (was) related to the (not) empty href. You're talking about a anchor element (<a/>), do you? The browser won't send a request on page load. Neither would the hash trigger this on click. Your logs could include multiple users interaction or one user who does reloads (GET) of the initial page because your application is slow as hell when the GC tries to free some memory. The 99% memory consumption might occur somewhere else and this is just a result.